# Name for "the set described by characteristic function f"

Tags: elementary-set-theory, terminology, characteristic-functions

Given a set $A$, there is a function called its "characteristic function", usually denoted $\chi_A$, $\mathbf{1}_A$, $I_A$, or $K_A$, defined as follows:

$$
\chi_A(x) =
\begin{cases}
1 &\text{if } x \in A, \\
0 &\text{if } x \notin A.
\end{cases}
$$

Conversely, given some function $a$ such that for all $x$, $a(x)\in\{0,1\}$, we can use it as a characteristic function to construct a set:

$$?_a=\{x\mid a(x)=1\}$$

Does the set induced by $a$ have a commonly used name or symbol? Or is there even just a more concise notation to construct it?

Comment: The support, or the preimage of 1. But in this very special case you should probably draw attemtion to the assumption.

Comment: You should include an explicit statement of your terminology. Something along the lines of "We write $X_a$ to denote the subset of $X$ given by $\{x\in X\mid a(x)=1\}$." or something like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called the [support](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_(mathematics)) of $f$. It comes up quite a it in analysis.

Comment: I would still add an explicit explanation of the terminology. This is not as standard in set theoretic contexts.